# why dont IDE's offer built in code timing like break points?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, benchmarking

I find timing my code for performance to be a bit of a headache and I have to assume this is a common problem for folks.

Adding in a bunch of code to time my loops is great but often there is more overhead in adding the timing checks than adding a parallel task.
making a loop parallel can take seconds whereas adding in timing chunks requires several lines of code and be dangerous if forgotten.

So... My question is why dont IDE's include this ability to time chunks of code like a break point?
Something like i mark a section of code and tell it to dump the timing output to a console with some options to make it more readable. averages and such.

I know break points can seriously hamper performance but there must be an easier way to time specific chunks of code then to write all my own timing routines for each chunk of code i want to check.

Comment: Why time it? Just profile it and remove any bottlenecks *identified*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, VS 2015 [*does* offer timing indicators while debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/may/visual-studio-2015-analyze-performance-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015).

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC798936.png))</sub>

But I say don't use it for serious profiling purposes. Use it to get a *very rough* idea of what's going on.

Timing anything in a debug build **yields unreliable figures**, because of many factors (disabled compiler optimizations, disabled JIT optimizations, `nop` instructions everywhere, breakpoints, etc). Garbage in, garbage out.

Just do your profiling properly, it's a *hard* thing to get right. And use a real profiler for that if you need detailed performance data.

Comment: I know it can time things in an overall manner. But i just want my loop timed. i dont see a way to do that in the performance analyzer. i can see method timing but not specific loop timing. Oh wait a minute this is for VS2015. i take pevious versions dont have this... time to upgrade i guess. Hrmm i guess the performance analyzer can do line by line but its kind of a bear to use and read.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used the built-in performance analyzer. I use dotTrace for profiling, which can give line-by-line execution statistics such as elapsed time and number of calls. You may want to take a look at this, it's part of ReSharper.